# Changes not getting in effect Rest Webservice

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-rest

I have just started learning rest services and have made a simple test rest service using Spring MVC. The first time it ran smoothly, but now since I have changed the `@RequestMapping` it is displaying the result on the same old URL. 
If I remove the web service from the server it gets unavailable but when redeploying, the same problem. Its giving result on the same old `URL mapping` and not the new one.

Here's the code

**Controller**

```
import javax.websocket.server.PathParam;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class SimpleResponseController {

    //Earlier and still coming : @RequestMapping(value = "/greet", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @RequestMapping(value = "/sayhi", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String giveResponseBodyParams(@RequestParam("greeting") String greeting){
        System.out.println("In BodyParms");
        return "Your Message : "+ greeting +" \t Hello, How may I help you using Body Parameters";
    }


}
```

**Dispatcher-Servlet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">  

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.sopra" />
<!--     <mvc:annotation-driven /> -->

</beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
  <display-name>RestSpringSimpleDemo</display-name>

 <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>
                org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
            </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

PS: Please understand I am learning and mention any additional details or edits in comments

Answer (score 1):

Actually, It was a bug (i guess )in eclipse, It was not synchronizing project behind the scenes. Now I restarted it, the problem got solved.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use @RestController For Rest Web Services.
You have not initialised contextConfigLocation of the servlet. Also You have not passed the context parameter in web.xml file. 
Therefore spring container will not be  initialised properly.

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/Dispatcher-Servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
   <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
   <init-param>
     <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
     <param-value>/WEB-INF/Dispatcher-Servlet.xml</param-value>
   </init-param>
   <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```